# Image slider does not work with ajax content loader

Tags: jquery, ajax

When combined with my ajax content loader, my image slider does not work, but the slider alone does work. When I try it on my website, the image slider only works when I refresh the page. Any ideas why these aren't working together?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//menu loader
$('.n3').click(function() {
  $('#secNav').toggle();
  return false;
});
$('.n1 a, .n2 a, .n4 a').click(function() {
  $('#secNav').hide();
});


//content loader in portfolio div      
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
var href = $('.n1 a, .n2 a, .n4 a, #secNav a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){
        var toLoad = hash+'.html #portfolio';
        $('#portfolio').load(toLoad)
    }                                           
});

$('.n1 a, .n2 a, .n4 a, #secNav a').click(function(){

var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #portfolio';
$('#portfolio').fadeOut("fast",loadContent);
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);
function loadContent() {
    $('#portfolio').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())
}
function showNewContent() {
    $('#portfolio').fadeIn("1000");
}
return false;
});


//active link diff color

    $("#nav a").click( function() { 
              $("#nav a").css("color", "#000");
              $(this).css("color", "#85f1f5");
            });

$("#secNav a").click( function() { 
              $("#secNav a").css("color", "#000");
              $(this).css("color", "#ff2712");
            });

$("#nav a").click( function() { 
              $("#secNav a").css("color", "#000");
            });




//end of doc ready
});


//image slider

$(window).load(function(){

// We are listening to the window.load event, so we can be sure
// that the images in the slideshow are loaded properly.


// Testing whether the current browser supports the canvas element:
var supportCanvas = 'getContext' in document.createElement('canvas');

// The canvas manipulations of the images are CPU intensive,
// this is why we are using setTimeout to make them asynchronous
// and improve the responsiveness of the page.

var slides = $('#slideshow li'),
    current = 0,
    slideshow = {width:0,height:0};

setTimeout(function(){

    window.console && window.console.time && console.time('Generated In');

    if(supportCanvas){
        $('#slideshow img').each(function(){

            if(!slideshow.width){
                // Taking the dimensions of the first image:
                slideshow.width = this.width;
                slideshow.height = this.height;
            }

            // Rendering the modified versions of the images:
            createCanvasOverlay(this);
        });
    }

    window.console && window.console.timeEnd && console.timeEnd('Generated In');

    $('#slideshow .arrow').click(function(){
        var li          = slides.eq(current),
            canvas      = li.find('canvas'),
            nextIndex   = 0;

        // Depending on whether this is the next or previous
        // arrow, calculate the index of the next slide accordingly.

        if($(this).hasClass('next')){
            nextIndex = current >= slides.length-1 ? 0 : current+1;
        }
        else {
            nextIndex = current <= 0 ? slides.length-1 : current-1;
        }

        var next = slides.eq(nextIndex);

        if(supportCanvas){

            // This browser supports canvas, fade it into view:

            canvas.fadeIn(function(){

                // Show the next slide below the current one:
                next.show();
                current = nextIndex;

                // Fade the current slide out of view:
                li.fadeOut(function(){
                    li.removeClass('slideActive');
                    canvas.hide();
                    next.addClass('slideActive');
                });
            });
        }
        else {

            // This browser does not support canvas.
            // Use the plain version of the slideshow.
            current=nextIndex;
            next.addClass('slideActive').show();
            li.removeClass('slideActive').hide();
        }
    });

},100);

// This function takes an image and renders
// a version of it similar to the Overlay blending
// mode in Photoshop. 
// **NOTE: REMOVED COLOR CHANGES

function createCanvasOverlay(image){

    var canvas          = document.createElement('canvas'),
        canvasContext   = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Make it the same size as the image
    canvas.width = slideshow.width;
    canvas.height = slideshow.height;

    // Drawing the default version of the image on the canvas:
    canvasContext.drawImage(image,0,0);


    // Taking the image data and storing it in the imageData array:
    var imageData   = canvasContext.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height),
        data        = imageData.data;

    // Putting the modified imageData back to the canvas.
    canvasContext.putImageData(imageData,0,0);

    // Inserting the canvas in the DOM, before the image:
    image.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas,image);
}

//end of window load    
});
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML as well. This will help potential responders solve your problem and find you the best possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing one slider element for a new one with your ajax, you have to reinitialize the slider code to work on the new html

Pseudo code example

```
$('#sliderWrapper').load(  url, function(){

   /* new html exists, run all pertinent slider code*/
})
```

It would help a lot if you removed all unrelated code like nav code etc to sort out what is what with regard to your specific problem. It's not very clear which parts are slider related

Also make sure you aren't loading jQuery again and wiping out the original jQuery object